# Find nth term given the equation of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I want to find the $n$<sup>th</sup> term when the sum of the series is given.

In general, this is done by $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$.
But I don't get it why I am not getting the same answer with $s_{n+1} - s_n$.

Shouldn't they both give $a_n$ (the general term)?

Comment: Then, following your generality clause, don't you think you would be getting $a_{n+1}$ instead?

Comment: It would give $a_{n+1}$ term.

Comment: Because in general $s_{n+1}-s_n$ is not the same as $s_n-s_{n-1}$?